# Iterate through all device token in MySQL table to send push notification is really slow if many tokens

Tags: php, ios, web-services, push-notification, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to create my web api to send Push notification in my iOS app. There is some scenaries where the same push message should be send to multiple devices. Right now I iterate (foreach) through all the device token and send the push message to each device, it is really slow when there is many devices. How can I make it faster even if there is over 1000 devices.

Here is my shitty code so far...

```
foreach ($devices as $device)
            {
                $user = $device->user;

                //don't notify user if the users device is already in the array, if the user owns the post or if the user is the one who comment
                if (!in_array($device->device_token, $DeviceTokenArray) && $user->id != $post->user->id /*&& $user->id != $commentUser->id*/) {
                    $deviceToken = $device->device_token;
                    $message = PushNotification::Message('Ny kommentar - '. $post->title, array(
                        'badge' => 1,
                        'sound' => 'example.aiff',

                        'custom' => array('data' => array(
                            'id' => $post->id,

                        ))
                    ));
                    PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                        ->to($deviceToken)
                        ->send($message);
                    array_push($DeviceTokenArray, $device->device_token);

                    if(!in_array($user->id, $commentUserArray))
                    {
                        $notify = new Notification();
                        $notify->fullname = $commentUser->firstname . " " . $commentUser->lastname;
                        $notify->description = $commentUser->firstname . " " . $commentUser->lastname . " " . "har kommenteret annoncen," . " " . $post->title;
                        $notify->photourl = $commentUser->photourl;
                        $notify->post_id = $post->id;

                        $user->notifications()->save($notify);
                        array_push($commentUserArray, $user->id);

                    }



                }

            }
```

Comment: There are different reasons that could lead your code to be slow. The first is probably the `PushNotification` object. How does the `send()` method works? Is it synchronously sending the notification? If so this is probably why your code is slow. You should build an array of push notifications and send them all at once.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it is synchronously. I'm using this third party component: https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Comment: This components lets you send a single notification to a collection of devices. You should try this first. Depending how this component has implemented it this could be much faster.

Comment: Also, I don't know where this piece of code fits in your app, but sending a lot of notifications is always going to be slow. This is not something that you should do synchronously when a user saves a post for example. You should have some sort of background job that handles sending notifications.

Comment: first thing first thank for your reply @deadbeef. I'll will try the method which send one notification to a collection of devices, did not see that in the doc. You are right These kind of task should be done in the background, but I do not have a clue how to do that in laravel php.